# Complex geometric series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Prove that if $|z|=1$, the following series diverge :

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^k $

---

all the tests that I know failed here, so I used  :

$\displaystyle z= \cos x+ i \sin x \rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos n x +i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin nx\ \ \ \ $   (for some real $x$)

we get partial sums for the sum of $\cos nx $ and $\sin nx$ but it's hard enough to show that it limit doesn't exist.

do you have any ideas? (please give me just hints)

thank you.

Comment: Hint: If a series $\sum_{k} a_k$ converges, the sequence $a_k$ will converge to $0$. Does you $z^k$ converge to $0$?

Comment: thank you achille, I've forgotten the most basic test LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $|z|=1$, then $z$ is determined by its angle $\zeta$ (measured from right wing of $x$-axis), and $z^k$ has angle $k\zeta$. I would distinguish two cases according to $\zeta/2\pi$ being rational or irrational.

For example, if it is rational, the series becomes a periodic sequence  having *more* congestion points.